# Append new data to formatted xlsx worksheet using R

Tags: xml, r, excel, formatting, data-cleaning

I'm trying to use the `xlsx` package to help with the cleaning of a complex dataset, as new data comes in.  I'm aiming for a workflow that looks like the following:

1. Import the data into R, do some coded data cleaning.
2. Write the data as an xls file, save it to a dropbox folder
3. Non-R-literate colleagues (and myself) can then do manual data cleaning
4. As more data comes in, I repeat step 1, and then append it to the existing XLS file, *retaining formatting* such as highlighting, comments, or bolding.

Finally, I'm curious if it is relevant that I'm hoping for this to work across LibreOffice (in Linux, which I use) and Excel (in Windows, which colleagues use).

At the moment, I'm having trouble finding a way to append data to an existing spreadsheet without entirely re-writing it (and thereby losing any formatting).

Here is an example of what I'd like to be able to do, using the pre-loaded `iris` dataset:

```
#Import data, do some coded cleaning:
data = iris[1:10,]
data$Sepal.Ratio = with(data, Sepal.Length/Sepal.Width)
data$Sepal.Length = NULL
data$Sepal.Width = NULL
data$Species = as.character(data$Species)

#Write to excel...
write.xlsx(data,file="ss.xls")

#Manually make some changes
system('soffice /path/to/ss.xls')
```

(see screenshots)
[image]
[image]

```
#Load and clean more data...
data = iris[11:20,]
data$Sepal.Ratio = with(data, Sepal.Length/Sepal.Width)
data$Sepal.Length = NULL
data$Sepal.Width = NULL
data$Species = as.character(data$Species)

#Append it to the existing spreadsheet, while preserving previous formatting
???
```

The `append=TRUE` option isn't much help here, as it's designed to simply add worksheets to a workbook.

Alternatively, is it possible to read the spreadsheet's formatting into some sort of R object, and then apply it to a rewritten file, doing something like the following?

```
olddat = read.xls('/path/to/ss.xls')
formatting <- someFunctionToExtractFormatting('/path/to/ss.xls')
newdata = rbind(olddata,data)
write.xlsx(newdata,file="ss.xls", FORMATTING=formatting)
```

There are a few similar commands that allow me to define formatting from R, but I'm not finding commands that can read and then re-write formatting

Comment: Perhaps you can reconsider your workflow. If you add columns with extra, data cleaning information (e.g. add a label 1 in the importance column when a record is being considered important.), then you can save your data frame as a .csv file, read it in again to add new records and save it as the same .csv file with keeping all the labels in the extra columns.

Comment: Sorry for accidentally putting my comment as an answer. Please can anyone remove it? Couldn't do it myself.

Answer (score 1):

The `XLConnect` package is able to do this kind of stuff. Have a look at `? appendWorksheet`.

```
library(XLConnect)
wb <- loadWorkbook( "ss.xlsx" )
appendWorksheet( wb, data, sheet = "iris" ) # iris is the sheet you want to append data to
saveWorkbook( wb )
```